# Cannot determine why I'm getting "Unexpected token }"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for a syntax-related question, but I've tried all the debugging I can do myself and don't see anything wrong. My entire JavaScript file so far is

```
$(function () { // equivalent to $(document).ready(function() { 

    // div that holds the game area
    var snakeBoardHolder = $('#snake-board-holder');
    // make it have the same height as width
    snakeBoardHolder.height(snakeBoardHolder.width());

    // draw canvas for the snake to live on
    // http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael
    if (!Raphael.svg) throw new Error("Your browser does not support SVG elements! Game won't work.");
    var snakeBoard = Raphael("snake-board-holder", snakeBoardHolder.width(), snakeBoardHolder.height());

    // make the game area (div) have height always equal to width,
    // and make the Raphel object (canvas) inside it have the same dimensions 
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var w = snakeBoardHolder.width();
        snakeBoardHolder.height(w);
        snakeBoard.setSize(w, w);
    });


    // define snake object
    function Snake ( )
    {


    }

    // define game object
    function Game ( board, blocksVert, blocksHorz ) 
    {
        //      board: Raphael object that the snake will live on
        // blocksVert: height of the game in blocks
        // blocksHorz: width of the game in blocks 

        var board = this.board;
        var snake; // Snake object on the board
        var openCoords; // coordinates on which the snake is not living at the moment

        function startNew ( ) 
        {
            this.snake = new Snake ();
            this.openCoords = new Array ();
        }
    }

    // start new snake game
    var SG = new Game(snakeBoard, 16, 16);
    SG.startNew();

});
```

and my Google Chrome console is telling me

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

and is pointing to the line

```
function startNew ( )
```

I apologize if this turns out to be something really obvious.

Comment: Don't see any Syntax Error in the above code, it must be coming from somewhere else

Comment: It looks like you have `var board` defined twice... i think you could probably do `board = this.board;`

Comment: No Syntax error in the given code, try isolating code

Comment: @l'L'l Thanks, that was a type-o by me. Should've just been `this.board = board;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define your javascript function inside `$(function(){...});`, keep it outside of `$(function(){...});` but inside `<script>` tag.

```
$(function () { // equivalent to $(document).ready(function() { 

    // div that holds the game area
    var snakeBoardHolder = $('#snake-board-holder');
    // make it have the same height as width
    snakeBoardHolder.height(snakeBoardHolder.width());

    // draw canvas for the snake to live on
    // http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael
    if (!Raphael.svg) throw new Error("Your browser does not support SVG elements! Game won't work.");
    var snakeBoard = Raphael("snake-board-holder", snakeBoardHolder.width(), snakeBoardHolder.height());

    // make the game area (div) have height always equal to width,
    // and make the Raphel object (canvas) inside it have the same dimensions 
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var w = snakeBoardHolder.width();
        snakeBoardHolder.height(w);
        snakeBoard.setSize(w, w);
    });

    // start new snake game
    var SG = new Game(snakeBoard, 16, 16);
    SG.startNew();

});


// define snake object
    function Snake ( )
    {


    }

    // define game object
    function Game ( board, blocksVert, blocksHorz ) 
    {
        //      board: Raphael object that the snake will live on
        // blocksVert: height of the game in blocks
        // blocksHorz: width of the game in blocks 

        var board = this.board;
        var snake; // Snake object on the board
        var openCoords; // coordinates on which the snake is not living at the moment

        function startNew ( ) 
        {
            this.snake = new Snake ();
            this.openCoords = new Array ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: and why is that, can you help a JavaScript Novice like me.. by letting me know of more details on that. ?

Comment: bcoz jquery doen't recognize javascript function and take it as syntactical error, if you really want to define function then define it like `var Snake = function(){ ... };`

Comment: Problem ended up being browser caching issues. Sorry.

Comment: Your explanation is completely wrong. jQuery is a library, it does not influence syntax in any way. It's perfectly fine to have a function declaration inside a function, as you demonstrated yourself.

Comment: @Larry: then you should not accept this answer just for the sake of accepting it.